# Where to download these three files, "owmctab.plb","owmaggrs.plb","owmaggrb.plb"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, wm-concat

I need use `WM_CONCAT()` function,but the oracle `11g` haven't.

> Some articles say the problem can be fixed through these three files
>    "**owmctab.plb**,**owmaggrs.plb**,**owmaggrb.plb**".

So i want to download that files,where i can download?

plase get me some clues! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WM_CONCAT` is an **undocumented** function and as such is **not supported** by Oracle for user applications, and even **not exists** in `DB version 11 Release 2+`.

You can use `listagg()` function alternatively as

```
select deptno, listagg(ename, ',') within group (order by ename) as employees
  from emp
 group by deptno;
```

instead of

```
select deptno, wm_concat(ename, ',') as employees
  from emp
 group by deptno;
```